# Labeling a class that inherits from Superclass, mongoengine

Tags: python, inheritance, mongoengine

In mongoengine, if a Document inherits from another Document class it gets a `_cls` attribute applied to it that identifies it as an instance of the subclass. All objects that inherit from the same Superclass are stored in the same collection.

```
Supe(Document):
    pass

Sub(Supe):
    pass
```

And instance of Sub would have `_cls="Supe.Sub"`. As it is a mongoengine convention, `_cls` is not passed along when an object is pulled from the collection and returned as JSON. Of course, I always want the objects that match the query, but sometimes I want to display different subclasses in slightly different ways and have resorted to seeing if they have a subclass-specific attribute.

Would it be proper to label subclasses like this:

```
Sub(Supe):
    kind = StringField(default='sub')
    ...
```

It makes me feel like I'm missing the point of inheritance or at least the way mongoengine does it.

Answer (score 0):

> "As it is a mongoengine convention, _cls is not passed along when an
>   object is pulled from the collection and returned as JSON"

Ofcourse `_cls` key can be retrieved from database, you can use this to categorize your objects.

> Would it be proper to label subclasses like this:
>
> ```
>  Sub(Supe):
>      kind = StringField(default='sub')
> ```

Yes, why not? when you need extra info is OK to store it to match your app logic. But I think you don't need this since you can access `_cls` attribute.